# With MACH-O is there a way to register a function that will run before main?

Tags: c, macos, mach-o

Under Linux, I can register a routine that will run before main. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myinit(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
  printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);
}
__attribute__((section(".init_array"))) typeof(myinit) *__init = myinit;
```

By compiling this with GCC and linking it in, the function **myinit** will be run before main.

Is there way to do this under Mac OSX and MACH-O?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could place the function in `__mod_init_func` data section of Mach-O binary.

From [Mach-O format reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/index.html):

> __DATA,__mod_init_func
>
> Module initialization functions. The C++ compiler places static constructors here.

example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myinit(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
  printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);
}
__attribute__((section("__DATA,__mod_init_func"))) typeof(myinit) *__init = myinit;

int main() {
  printf("%s: %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);
  return 0;
}
```

I build your example with `clang` on OS X platform:

```
$ clang -Wall example.c
$ ./a.out
example.c: myinit
example.c: main
```

Comment: What I need is to be able to do is:

Comment: If you separate main from myinit then `gcc myinit.c main.c; ./a.out` doesn't work but `clang myinit.c main.c; ./a.out` does.  Any idea as to why? What is nice is that `clang -c myinit.c; gcc main.c myinit.o; ./a.out` does work.

Comment: Maybe `gcc` optimizes it away. I don't have `gcc` installed here, but you can try to add `used` attribute. I would also add `aligned` to be on the safe side: `__attribute__((section("__DATA,__mod_init_func"), used, aligned(sizeof(void*)))) typeof(myinit) *__init = myinit;`

Comment: If gcc is /usr/bin/gcc then it is clang and it works fine.  If gcc is in my case a brew installed gcc 4.9.2 then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to specify the function to be constructor using constructor attribute. The constructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters `main()`. Similarly, the destructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically after `main()` completes or `exit()` is called. You can also specify optional priority if you have several functions

e.g. `__attribute__((constructor(100)))`

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) void myinit() {
    printf("my init\n");
}

int main() {
    printf("my main\n");
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((destructor)) void mydeinit() {
    printf("my deinit\n");
}


$ clang -Wall example.c
$ ./a.out
my init
my main
my deinit
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I generally discourage what I'm about to say. Having code running before or after `main` makes things less predictable. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just let the first line of `main` invoke your `myinit`, but I suppose everyone has a reason. Here goes.

I don't know much about Mach-O, but the simplest way to run code before main, is to link in a C++ class that has a corresponding global instance defined.  You can do this independently of your "C" code without having to alter anything else.  You can also have this C++ code invoke C functions defined elsewhere in your code.  In the example below, I show a simple example of how I would invoke your `myinit`.

In a standalone .cpp (or .cc) file, declare a very simple C++ class with a constructor that calls your "myinit function".

### foo.cpp

```
// forward declare your myinit function and designate "C" linkage
extern "C" myinit(int, char**, char**);

class CodeToRunBeforeMain
{
 public:
    CodeToRunBeforeMain()
    {
        // invoke your myinit function here
        myinit(0, NULL, NULL);
    }

};

// global instance - constructor will run before main.
CodeToRunBeforeMain g_runBeforeMain;
```

The above approach doesn't recognize argc, argv, or envp. Hopefully, that isn't important.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I still stand by my answer. I made a reasonable attempt to give the pros/cons and was well aware that the OP was looking for a "C" answer. But the I answer I gave is fairly portable and to most anyone with C tools installed.  Can't make everyone happy.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my case, I would like some 'modules' of code to self register with a central list - so these init functions just append to some global array.
I can (and was) doing all that in main, this avoids a bunch of boilerplate - main.c having to know about each and every module, etc. The array is now magically populated with whatever modules are linked into the app, which is nice.